# Heathkit IP-27 bench PSU min. stays at 0.18V and there is a +0.1V for all the readings?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current, calibration

I've recently acquired a Heathkit IP-27 bench power supply. The supply itself works quite fine except that the minimum voltage it can be turned down to with the coarse adjustment is only 0.18V, doesn't zero out. It wouldn't go down any further. Lets say for example I set to 10V, it is actually 10.18V when measured with multimeter. I tried the calibration procedure but still the issue persists. Is this due to a fault with the device or is it just that the PSU is just like that?

I've attached a link to the manual for the IP-27 for reference. The only additional mod I did was add the zener+capacitor for protecting the transistor when changing the voltage knob as per the manual.

http://www.rsp-italy.it/Electronics/Kits/_contents/Heathkit/Kits/Heathkit%20IP-27%20power%20supply.pdf

Comment: It’s probably the normal limitation of a single turn pot at 2%

Comment: Is your multimeter accurate?

Comment: @EdgarBrown Yes, I double checked the voltage with another Omega multimeter from work and the voltage is correct.